# finding kernel version in the docker image

Tags: centos, kernel, docker

I'm using a docker image and trying to see which packages are installed.  Specifically which kernel packages.

Doing this command I get the following kernel packages

```
rpm -qa kernel*
kernel-devel-2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.i686
kernel-headers-2.6.32-754.17.1.el6.centos.plus.i686
```

but it's missing... how do I find verify that specific kernel is running.

```
kernel-2.6.32-754.3.5.el6.i686.rpm
```

From what I read the docker image uses the native OS kernel to execute commands.  But I'm attempting to confirm that this is the kernel-2.6.32-754.3.5.el6.i686.rpm. the documentation states is running.

thanks

Comment: `uname -r` tells you the kernels idea of the kernel version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A docker image doesn't have a Kernel, It uses the Kernel from the host machine that you are running Docker on. You can run this command inside your Docker container and from your CentOS host, It will show up the same result

```
uname -sr
```

There is a similar question on [**Super User**](https://superuser.com/questions/889472/docker-containers-have-their-own-kernel-or-not)

Ps:// By the way, you should upgrade your CentOS host to kernel 3.10+ as recommended [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/faq/#what-platforms-does-docker-run-on)

Comment: yeah that's what I suspected.  Also came across that thread but thought maybe I was missing something since they didn't show how they got there.. thanks